# google-play-services_lib Not working Properly

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I want to use google map in my application

I Have Added google-play-services_lib as project and set as library , And then i have added google-play-services_lib to my project

**if i check again it marked as red icon**

[image]

Can you please help to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you haven't imported the library in correct way.In order to work, the library project and your main project need to be in the same workspace. While importing `google-play-services` to  eclipse make sure you have checked `Copy Projects into workspace` option as shown in the below image,

[image]

Else you can also copy paste the `google-play-services` library project into your workspace and then import it from there.

Comment: Thanks you . That Issue is fixed now

Comment: but now am getting this issue .......   "   Type GoogleMap cannot be resolved to a type MainActivity.java /map/src/com/nidhin/map line 18 Java Problem   "

Comment: have you imported `import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;` ?

Comment: Thanks .. But Again one more issue  ....  "  MapFragment cannot be resolved to a type MainActivity.java /map/src/com/nidhin/map line 40 Java Problem
 "

Answer (score 0):

You no longer need to add the Google Play Service library in your project. Adding

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
```

under dependencies does the job.

Edit:
If you don't know how to add dependencies in Eclipse, take a look [here](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/manifest_editor/dependencies.htm).
In Android Studio (or any other Gradle based IDE), just open build.gradle and add the above line between dependencies brackets.